# Get the post method payload in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to get the payload sent by the post method in an asp.net webform. I have a `login.aspx` page called by another site as the post method like this:

```
https://example.com/Login/Login.aspx
```

How can I get the value of `SAMLResponse` from the payload? I've tried both of the below:

```
Request["SAMLResponse"] 
Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Posting images of technical information like this, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here for your question to be downvoted and ignored.

Comment: Also, typically a SAML response will post to a different address from the login page. The different address if for running the Assertion Consumer Service, and since it's not even a full page you ever show to the user it might also be just a "handler". Therefore a more typical name is "`acs.ashx`"

Comment: Another thing: it's clear the `Request` values are not giving you what you expect, but what DO you see? In what way is it failing?

Comment: In staging site by using Request.Form["SAMLResponse"] in global.asax page I am able to get the value but in production it is null. Did anybody know why it is working in staging and not working in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue of SAMLResponse is empty when request reach to login page. By using  Request.Form["SAMLResponse"] in global.asax page I am able to get the value. Thanks